# Binding Hierarchical TreeView To Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, treeview

I'm trying to get my TreeView to bind to a Dictionary that will be updated. I've implemented INotifyProperyChangedHandler on the data type itself, but will this effect the treeview at all?

What I'm aiming for is:

```
-FolderName
--->Item1
--->Item2
-FolderName
--->Item1
```

This is my View:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate" >
        <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding Path=m_Items}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}">
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding m_Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TreeView x:Name="NewTree" ItemsSource="{Binding m_FolderList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}">
    </TreeView>
```

My ViewModel:

```
    public Dictionary<UInt16, Folder> m_FolderList
    {
        get { return Manager.Instance.GetFolderDirectory(); }
    }
```

My Folder class:

```
public class Folder
{
     public m_Name { get; set; }
     public ObservableCollection<String> m_Items { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm getting is a blank treeview that never updates. Whenever I add a new item to the "FolderDirectory" in that singleton manager instance, I do an OnPropertyChanged call. Which works for anything else I've been binding to that dictionary or Folder item.

I was trying to follow this, but how the binding observes that it automatically childrens the "FamilyMembers" list escapes me because nowhere do you explicitly tell the XAML template that it should bind itemsource to that collection. http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/treeview-data-binding-multiple-templates/

EDIT:
The control is definitely getting all the values from my singleton. I just was playing around with the naming of the Binding Path and when I accidentally set the TreeView to bind to m_FolderList.Value (dictionaries have Values, not just Value), it gave me as many binding errors in the console as there were Items in the dictionary.

EDIT2:

```
public List<Folder> m_FolderList
{
  get
  {
    List<Folder> list = new List<Folder>();
    list.AddRange(Manager.Instace.GetFolderDirectory().Values);
    return list;
  }
}
```

If I do this, instead of Dictionary, the first Level of information appears... Which is a nuisance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<Folder> m_FolderList
{
        get
        {

                List<Folder> list = new List<Process>();
                list.AddRange(Manager.Instance.GetFolderDirectory().Values);
                return list;
        }
}
```

I hate doing this, but its the only method that worked here with the Heirarchical template. I've used a binding to dictionary Path=Value before numerous times but it just refused to work in this instance with many attempts. Its not the best answer, but its the only working one I have at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="secondLevel">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate  x:Key="topLevel" ItemsSource="{Binding Value.m_Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource secondLevel}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.m_Name}">
        </TextBlock>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TreeView x:Name="FolderTree" ItemsSource="{Binding m_FolderList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource topLevel}">
    </TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

> output
>   [image]

Comment: Its weird, its not giving me anything at all.

When I change from a Dictionary to a List, and manually iterate over the Dictionary values to insert them into a basic List<Folder> it works fine. (obviously without Value in the binding)

Comment: Why you are using Dictionary? Why you do not use List<Folder>.

Comment: Because I manage the collection of Folders (which is huge) with a dictionary, which I need to lookup by IDs. Unless I want to keep 2 copies of the same data, a List isn't conducive for 1000+ items

Comment: And even with the List<Folder>, for some reason, Items wont appear as children.

Comment: Ok i thought you did it because of TreeView because there it is of no use.

Comment: Oh yeah, its quite cumbersome with the Dictionary. I might just have to do it this way. Its just weird because Ive done it with Value and Dictionary before. I got the Items to appear with List<Folder> under children, the path name was wrong of course. I'm going to muck around more with your suggestion and Dictionary, maybe there is something Im missing with the Type naming.